# Singleton, async, ReaderWriterLock

Tags: c#

When I use multithreading app and have singleton resource. In this singleton when another thread go to don't show change of state.

```
public class WhoConnect
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim userLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private const int timeout = 2000;
    private List<User> users = new List<User>();

    private WhoConnect() { }

    public static WhoConnect Instance => instance ?? instance = new WhoConnect();

    public List<User> Users 
    {
        get
        {
            userLock.TryEnterReadLock(timeout);
            try { return users; }
            finally { userLock.ExitReadLock(); }
        }
    } 
    public void AddUser(string sessionId, string characterName, int characterID, int terminalId, string ip, string language)
    {
        userLock.TryEnterWriteLock(timeout);
        try
        {
            users.Add(new User(sessionId, characterName, characterID, terminalId, ip, language));
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
        }
        finally { userLock.ExitWriteLock(); }
    }
}
```

And where I first use:

```
WhoConnect.Instance.AddUser(socketId, "haha", 44, 3, "xx", "pl");
```

and in another thread:

```
var k = WhoConnect.Instance.Users;
```

than when get users, my writebloc is on false, not true.

Comment: Please post the exact code you are using to test this. Also, you could have used a `ConcurrentBag<User>` which is suitable for multi-threading and you can omit the locking code

Comment: What code you need? my app is bigger to post it...
its work on list, but in some place have only string.

Comment: Very hard to guess what "my writebloc is on false" could mean.  The Instance property is not thread-safe, two threads could enter the if (instance == null) statement and create different WhoConnect objects.  Use the `Lazy<T>` class instead.  And there is no implied guarantee that the 2nd thread accesses Users *after* the AddUser call.  The returned List object is not thread-safe either, it can change when one thread is iterating it and another thread calls AddUser.  Consider adding FindUser().

Comment: >  when another thread go to don't show change of state

I'm trying really hard but I just don't know what you mean. Are you saying when another thread is running, the state of the singleton is not changing?

Comment: i check is the same instance of singleton (not create now, but get instance.)

Yep in one thread instance is diffrent in another...(but only for ReaderWriterLockSlim class...)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are using `TryEnterWriteLock()` and `TryEnterReadLock()` without checking if the lock was actually acqiured.
To fix it simply use `EnterWriteLock()` and `EnterReadLock()`, instead.

```
    public List<User> Users 
    {
        get
        {
            userLock.EnterReadLock()
            try { return users; }  // DON'T DO THIS!
            finally { userLock.ExitReadLock(); }
        }
    }
```

If you really need a timeout, you have to check if the lock was actually acquired, but then you have to handle the cases when the lock could not be acquired in time... so I doubt that this would be a good solution for your case. E.g.:

```
    public List<User> Users 
    {
        get
        {
            if(userLock.TryEnterReadLock(timeout))
            {
                try { return users; } // DON'T DO THIS!
                finally { userLock.ExitReadLock(); }
            }
            else throw new Exception("Could not acquire lock");
        }
    }
```

Another critical problem that I see is when simply returning the users-list under lock, the lock is rather useless, because the activity on the user-list is done in the method that is calling the Users property, but then the lock is already exited... Also, the list could be used for writing instead of reading, so a readlock might not be correct.
One solution is returning a copy of the elements from the list:

```
    public User[] Users 
    {
        get
        {
            userLock.EnterReadLock()
            try { return users.ToArray(); }
            finally { userLock.ExitReadLock(); }
        }
    }
```

Finally Hans Passant mentions a valid point in his comment that creating the instance is not thread safe. Either use `Lazy<T>` like proposed or use a lock.